# Getting error while trying to insert data into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I am trying to insert data into MongoDB using Play-scala and ReactiveMongo.

Here is my `DbimpService.scala`:

```
package services
import models.Post
import reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument
import reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver
import reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONCollection
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection
import reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteResult
import scala.concurrent.Future
import org.apache.xerces.util.DatatypeMessageFormatter

class Dbimpservice @Inject() (implicit ec:ExecutionContext) extends Dbservice {
    def create(p:Post):String={
            var status = "Not Saved"
                    val driver = new MongoDriver
                    val connection = driver.connection(List("localhost"))
                    val db = connection("application")
                    val collection = db[BSONCollection]("post")
                    val futureList = collection.insert[Post](p)
                    futureList.onComplete { case sucess => println(sucess) }
            return status
    }
}
```

Here is my `HomeController.scala`:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import models._
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success }
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import reactivemongo.api.{ MongoDriver, MongoConnection }
import reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection
import reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument
import reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteResult
import reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONCollection
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import services.Dbservice
import services.Dbimpservice
import services.Dbservice
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

/**
 * This controller creates an `Action` to handle HTTP requests to the
 * application's home page.
 */
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject() (implicit ec:ExecutionContext,val Dbservice : Dbimpservice)extends Controller {

    /**
     * Create an Action to render an HTML page with a welcome message.
     * The configuration in the `routes` file means that this method
     * will be called when the application receives a `GET` request with
     * a path of `/`.
     */
  def index  = Action{
    Ok("Hai")
  }

    def read = Action.async {
      val query = BSONDocument()
                    val driver = new MongoDriver
                    val connection = driver.connection(List("localhost:27017"))
                    val db = connection("application")
                    val collection = db[BSONCollection]("post")
                    val futureList = collection.find(query).cursor[Post]().collect[List]()
                    futureList.map { list =>
              Ok(list.toString())
          }
    }

    def create = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request => 
     val personResult = request.body.validate[Post]
    personResult.fold(
      errors => {
        BadRequest(Json.obj("status " ->"ERROR"))
      },
      valid = fun
    )
   }

    def fun:Post => Result= { post =>
      var ans = Dbservice.create(post)
      Ok(ans)
  }

}
```

I am trying to insert the data but not getting inserted and the error which i am getting is

```
Failure(reactivemongo.core.errors.ConnectionNotInitialized: MongoError['Connection is missing metadata (like protocol version, etc.) The connection pool is probably being initialized.'])
```

Some one please help me, I even referred the link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456517/embedmongo-with-reactivemongo-process-does-not-exit
```

but did not get

Comment: You need to indicate the version of the DB and of the lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing that you are using a recent version of ReactiveMongo (0.11.7+), you are using a [deprecated DB resolution](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.MongoConnection@apply(name:String,failoverStrategy:reactivemongo.api.FailoverStrategy)(implicitcontext:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):reactivemongo.api.DefaultDB) code (`connection(dbName)` aka `connection.apply(dbName)`.

> [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37853468/3347384)

You need to use the asynchronous resolution, which benefit from the failover (to handle possible network latency/incident). The following code must so be refactored.

```
val db = connection("application")
val collection = db[BSONCollection]("post")
val futureList = collection.insert[Post](p)
```

Using the new [DB resolution](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.MongoConnection@database(name:String,failoverStrategy:reactivemongo.api.FailoverStrategy)(implicitcontext:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[reactivemongo.api.DefaultDB]):

```
for {
  db <- connection.database("application")
  collection = db("post")
  res <- collection.insert(p)
} yield res
```